# PDO SQL Query Not Limiting

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, limit

I'm trying to get results from a query to the database but the LIMIT isn't working.  When I put LIMIT 10 it returns no results.  Am I missing something here?

Here is my code.  I'm trying to figure out what the reason is for this strange behavior.

```
$username = "derek";
$query = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE (needs=:username OR worker=:username1) ORDER BY CASE WHEN needs=:username2 THEN needsread ELSE workerread END, time DESC LIMIT 10');

$query->bindParam(':username', $username);
$query->bindParam(':username1', $username);
$query->bindParam(':username2', $username);
$query->execute();
```

Comment: You're binding to parameters that don't exist.

Comment: $username is in my code above just not in this code.  I'll put it in an edit.

Comment: You're binding to `:username1` and `:username2`, which don't exist in your query; last I checked, that causes errors.

Comment: I edited the code.  Still didn't affect the result.  I still get no results.  Any other guesses?

Comment: If you're using PDO, [PHP doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php): "You must include a unique parameter marker for each value you wish to pass in to the statement...You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name twice..."

Comment: Edited the code.  Still not working after the edit either.  Good bit of info to know though @Passerby

Comment: What would you get if you directly run this query in SQL console/phpMyAdmin?

Comment: It returns the appropriate amount of results.  Exactly what I would expect.

Comment: Have you tried putting your query in a try-catch statement?  I have other debugging ideas at the moment save that.

Comment: how would I do such a thing.  new to pdo and haven't heard of try-catch yet.  PS Dae are you the Daedalus from Unity Craft?  Random just wanted to know.

Comment: Never heard of Unity Craft, sorry.  And I meant '*I don't have'.. typo.  As to the try-catch, `try { /* build query, execute */ } catch (PDOException $e) { echo "MySQL error: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>"; die(); }`

Answer (score 1):

Ended up being something with my if statements.  I was getting the results but after filtering through my if statements the 10 results I wanted to show shouldn't have shown.  So after fixing my query to the database it worked.  Here's my query:

```
$workneed = "workneed";
$follow="follow";

$query = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE CASE WHEN needs=:username THEN type=:workneed END OR CASE WHEN worker=:username THEN type=:follow END ORDER BY CASE WHEN needs=:username THEN needsread ELSE workerread END, time DESC LIMIT 10');
$query->bindParam(':username', $username);
$query->bindParam(':workneed', $workneed);
$query->bindParam(':follow', $follow);
$query->execute();
```